# Ruby String Output

Tags: ruby, printf, string-formatting

My goal is to create a one line output with 3 different variables (all strings) that is formatted with the first variable being left aligned, the 2nd variable being centered, and the last variable being right aligned with spaces padding the variables if their size is less than the space allotted.

The variable slots are:
variables 1,3 = max string length of 10
variable 2 = max string length of 7
(there will be space buffers of 2 spaces between variables 1&2 and 2&3)

I would like variables 1&3 to be the same size (10) regardless of user input. If the input is less than 10, I want there to either being padding at the end (variable 1 - left aligned) or at the beginning (variable 3 - right aligned).

I've tried using/learning the sprintf methods with various formats and arguments but I keep getting errors or blank outputs all together.

```
****IDEAL OUTPUT EXAMPLE****

VARIABLE 1  VARIAB2  VARIABLE 3
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you post the snippets of code that you've attempted that haven't quite worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the various methods available in the [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/String.html) class.

```
input1 = 'one'
input2 = 'two'
input3 = 'three'

input1 = input1.ljust 10
 #=> "one       "
input2 = input2.center 7     #credit to user Simple Lime
 #=> "  two  "
input3 = input3.rjust 10
 #=> "     three"

puts output = input1 + '  ' + input2 + '  ' + input3
 #one           two         three
output.size
 #=> 31
```

Comment: @SimpleLime I see what you mean about the loop. Also I can't believe I missed `center`. Thanks, have updated my answer.

Comment: This is what I needed. Didn't realize there was a built-in method already in Ruby. Thank you for your help, this is perfect.